# Bulk insert in SQL Server database from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 200k records in one table and I want to insert these records into another table. I read about the bulk insert but the query I found on msdn website is just not making any sense.

This is the query

```
 BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
 FROM 'f:\orders\lineitem.tbl'
 WITH 
  (
     FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',
     ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'
  );
```

What is `f:\orders\lineitem.tbl` and the whole this is just not making any sense.

I have a table with four columns: id, frm, to1 and country

Same this in destination table

Any easy syntax will be helpful

I am using SQL Server 2008/12

Comment: File path actually makes sense. Database with its tables has to be stored somewhere on disk. It's not a void structure. There are many online tutorials for doing a copy of a table or just a part of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BULK INSERT imports from an external data file. If you already have the data in a SQL Server table, then you should do something like:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM OldTable
```

DO NOT point BULK INSERT at your SQL Server database file. The .tbl file referenced in your example code is to a text file with delimited fields.

Comment: half of the things you said I could not understand.  What do you mean by "DO NOT point BULK INSERT at your SQL Server database file..."

Comment: In the BULK INSERT command, there is the FROM 'filename' clause that should not have the name of your database file (as hinted at by Consider Me in his comment).

Answer (score 0):

Bulk insert is for import external data from file to sql table like

`BULK INSERT 'tableName' From 'File Path'`,

If You have Copy data from one table to other table in sql, use:

`select into instate insert into like ' select * into table1 From table2`

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into destinationsever.destinationdatabase.dbo.destinationtable
select * from sourcesever.sourcedatabase.dbo.sourcetable
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes